# Assign multiple drive letters to variables

Tags: windows, batch-file, variables, automation, format

I am writing a batch file and what started out as simple has begun to snowball into a larger project.  The more I have been learning the more I want to implement.  So the basis of my script is that I want it to automate the formatting and file copy process of multiple SD cards and the ability to choose between 2 different formats. Fair warning: some of these commands are 3rd party software from [this genius](http://www.uwe-sieber.de/english.html)(I mean that respectfully).  Here is what I have come up with so far:

```
@echo off

REM Set the variables below for the file path for the bin file and the drive letters for the sd cards.

SET BIN_PATH=
SET SD1=
SET SD2=

:start
Title Insert SD Cards
cls
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo Insert SD cards into the readers.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
pause

:ListDrives
Title Drives present?
restartsrdev %SD1%:
restartsrdev %SD2%:
cls
sleep 1
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO Are drives %SD1% and/or %SD2% listed below?
ECHO.
ECHO.
wmic logicaldisk get description,name
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO (Y) YES
ECHO (N) NO
set choice=
set /p choice=   
if not '%choice%'=='' set choice=%choice:~0,99%
if '%choice%'=='Y' goto FormatChoice
if '%choice%'=='y' goto FormatChoice
if '%choice%'=='N' goto Reseat
if '%choice%'=='n' goto Reseat
ECHO "%choice%" is not valid, try again
Pause.
GoTo ListDrives

:FormatChoice
Title FS Preferance
cls
echo.
echo.
echo Format to EXT4 or FAT32?
echo.
echo.
echo.
ECHO (1) FAT32
ECHO (2) EXT4
set choice=
set /p choice=   
if not '%choice%'=='' set choice=%choice:~0,99%
if '%choice%'=='1' goto FormatFAT32
if '%choice%'=='2' goto FormatEXT4
ECHO "%choice%" is not valid, try again
Pause.
GoTo FormatChoice

:FormatEXT4
Title Formatting SD Cards to EXT4
cls
echo.
mke2fs -t ext4 -L Label %SD1%:
echo.
echo.
mke2fs -t ext4 -L Label %SD2%:
echo.
echo.
start "Copying BIN to %SD1%:" cmd /c Robocopy %BIN_PATH% %SD1%:\ /e
start "Copying BIN to %SD2%:" cmd /c Robocopy %BIN_PATH% %SD2%:\ /e
echo.
echo.
pause
removedrive %SD1%: -l -47 -e
echo.
removedrive %SD2%: -l -47 -e
GoTo Choose

:FormatFAT32
Title Formatting SD Cards to FAT32
cls
echo.
echo.
echo.
format %SD1%: /fs:FAT32 /V:"" /Q /X
echo.
echo.
echo.
format %SD2%: /fs:FAT32 /V:"" /Q /X
echo.
echo.
echo.
start "Copying BIN to %SD1%:" cmd /c Robocopy %BIN_PATH% %SD1%:\ /e
start "Copying BIN to %SD2%:" cmd /c Robocopy %BIN_PATH% %SD2%:\ /e
echo.
cls
echo.

:Choose
cls
Title Transfer Complete
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo Please remove the SD cards from the readers.
echo.
echo Want to do it again? 
ECHO.
ECHO (1) Format again
ECHO (2) Exit
ECHO.
set choice=
set /p choice=   
if not '%choice%'=='' set choice=%choice:~0,99%
if '%choice%'=='1' goto start
if '%choice%'=='2' goto Exit
ECHO "%choice%" is not valid, try again
ECHO.
pause.
goto choose


:Exit
Exit

:Reseat
Title Reseat SD Cards
cls
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo Reseat the SD cards in the readers or
echo      turn the USB hub off/on
echo.
echo.
echo.
pause
GoTo ListDrives
```

My issue is that I want to be able to assign the discovered drive letters from this section of code:

```
for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2,3,4 " %%i in (`wmic logicaldisk get caption^,description^,drivetype 2^>NUL`) do (

if %%l equ 2 (
SET SD1=%%i
SET SD2=%%i
        )
        )
ECHO Are drives %SD1% and/or %SD2% listed below?
pause
```

to my variables SD1 and SD2.  There will never be more than two SD card readers plugged in at one time so that's not an issue.
Any kind of insight would be greatly appreciated.  I have done a lot of research and I apologize if this is a simple fix, but I am banging my head against a wall here.

UPDATE:
Here is what the final script ended up looking like in case anyone is interested...

```
@echo off

:start
Title Insert SD Cards
cls
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo Insert SD cards into the readers.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
pause
for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2,3,4 " %%i in (`wmic logicaldisk get caption^,description^,drivetype 2^>NUL`) do (
if %%l equ 2 (
IF NOT DEFINED SD1 (
set SD1=%%i
) ELSE (
set SD2=%%i
)
)
)
cls

:ListDrives
Title Drives present?
cls
sleep 1
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO Are drives %SD1% and/or %SD2% listed below?
ECHO.
ECHO.
wmic logicaldisk get description,name
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO (Y) YES
ECHO (N) NO
set choice=
set /p choice=   
if not '%choice%'=='' set choice=%choice:~0,99%
if '%choice%'=='Y' goto FormatChoice
if '%choice%'=='y' goto FormatChoice
if '%choice%'=='N' goto Reseat
if '%choice%'=='n' goto Reseat
ECHO "%choice%" is not valid, try again
Pause.
GoTo ListDrives

:FormatChoice
Title FS Preferance
cls
echo.
echo.
echo Format to EXT4 or FAT32?
echo.
echo.
echo.
ECHO (1) FAT32
ECHO (2) EXT4
set choice=
set /p choice=   
if not '%choice%'=='' set choice=%choice:~0,99%
if '%choice%'=='1' goto FormatFAT32
if '%choice%'=='2' goto FormatEXT4
ECHO "%choice%" is not valid, try again
Pause.
GoTo FormatChoice

:FormatEXT4
Title Formatting SD Cards to EXT4
FOR /F "tokens=1" %%I in (BIN_PATH.TXT) do SET BIN_PATH=%%I
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1,2,3,4 " %%i in (`wmic logicaldisk get caption^,description^,drivetype 2^>NUL`) do (
if %%l equ 2 (
IF NOT DEFINED SD1 (
set SD1=%%i
) ELSE (
set SD2=%%i
)
)
)
cls
echo.
mke2fs -t ext4 -L Label %SD1%
echo.
echo.
mke2fs -t ext4 -L Label %SD2%
echo.
echo.
start "Copying BIN to %SD1%" cmd /c Robocopy %BIN_PATH% %SD1%\ /e
start "Copying BIN to %SD2%" cmd /c Robocopy %BIN_PATH% %SD2%\ /e
echo.
echo.
pause
removedrive %SD1% -L -47 -e -i
echo.
removedrive %SD2% -L -47 -e -i
GoTo Choose

:FormatFAT32
FOR /F "tokens=1" %%I in (BIN_PATH.TXT) do SET BIN_PATH=%%I
for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2,3,4 " %%i in (`wmic logicaldisk get caption^,description^,drivetype 2^>NUL`) do (
if %%l equ 2 (
IF NOT DEFINED SD1 (
set SD1=%%i
) ELSE (
set SD2=%%i
)
)
)
Title Formatting SD Cards to FAT32
cls
echo.
echo.
echo.
format %SD1% /fs:FAT32 /V:"" /Q /X
echo.
echo.
echo.
format %SD2% /fs:FAT32 /V:"" /Q /X
echo.
echo.
echo.
start "Copying BIN to %SD1%" cmd /c Robocopy %BIN_PATH% %SD1%\ /e
start "Copying BIN to %SD2%" cmd /c Robocopy %BIN_PATH% %SD2%\ /e
echo.
cls

:Choose
cls
Title Transfer Complete
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo Please remove the SD cards from the readers.
echo.
echo Want to do it again? 
ECHO.
ECHO (1) Format again
ECHO (2) Exit
ECHO.
set choice=
set /p choice=   
if not '%choice%'=='' set choice=%choice:~0,99%
if '%choice%'=='1' goto start
if '%choice%'=='2' goto Exit
ECHO "%choice%" is not valid, try again
ECHO.
pause.
goto choose


:Exit
Exit

:Reseat
Title Reseat SD Cards
cls
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo Reseat the SD cards in the readers or
echo      turn the USB hub off/on
echo.
echo.
echo.
pause
GoTo ListDrives
```

Comment: I am not sure if I understand what your problem is.... The big code you provided seems unneccessary, but what exactly are you trying to achive with the smaller snippet and most importantly: What is your question?

Comment: Please read this help topic: [mcve]!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you say there will never be more than two plugged in, you can just use another IF statement

```
set SD1=
set SD2=
for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2,3,4 " %%i in (`wmic logicaldisk get caption^,description^,drivetype 2^>NUL`) do (
if %%l equ 2 (
IF NOT DEFINED SD1 (
set SD1=%%i
) ELSE (
set SD2=%%i
)
)
)
```

See http://ss64.com/nt/if.html for information about IF statements

Comment: Thank you.  I didn't even think of that.  All the glucose in the brain was used up by that point.  I knew it had to be something simple.  Once again I am new to script writing and not too fluent.  Thanks again!!